# Any decent client friendly CMS for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, extensions, cms, edit

I've got a client who really wants to manage things like copy, text, some images of their CMS pages (home page, about, etc). Currently they're all built in static blocks but editing these is very far removed from the actual design of the page and in the end they're still editing HTML which means they can destroy the site if they make a mistake.

Ideally, we'd have a section for each CMS page where every editable string, image etc is it's own form field - either textarea, file upload, etc. The homepage may have 25-30 editable elements.

Are there any good solutions for this? I've looked at wordpress integration's but they would require us to build this system in wordpress using custom fields etc and that doesn't feel that great considering we'd then have to maintain an entire wordpress install and integration.

Really appreciate any advice or suggestions!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have heard good things about this
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bluefoot-cms-and-page-builder.html

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @jwtea. OP: If you'd be interested in trying out a demo you can visit our website: https://www.bluefootcms.com/demo. I'm also happy to answer any questions you may have around the BlueFoot product.

Answer (score 0):

@jonsey: A user-friendly CMS that I use is concrete5.org .... regarding although I'm not aware of any integrations with this for Magento 2 just yet. I've been waiting to see some examples of Magento 2 and 3rd party CMS integrations to accomplish this myself.